# Wrapping a js confirm dialog in jQuery ajax success function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple requirement to display a JS confirm dialog dependant on a dynamic value . This value can be modified via AJAX on the webpage so it isn't possible to hard-code it on page load, so I use jQuery.ajax() to grab it when the onClick if fired. eg.

Note that the AJAX call returns the correct value.

HTML

```
    <a href='{% url program_pdf object.id %}' onClick='return check_time_budget();'>
        Download PDF
    </a>
```

JS

```
    function check_time_budget() {
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/program/check_duration/',
            data: { 'program_id': {{ instance.id }} },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.result != true){
                    return confirm("Your program estimated duration does not match the time allocated. Is this OK?");
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                return false;
            }
        });            
    }
```

I have fiddled with the returns, set vars etc, but can't seem to get the wrapped success function to successfully return the right value to the A tag.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I'm after?

EDIT:
I went back to using Dajaxice and a hack with SetTimeout

HTML

```
onClick='return dajaxice_wrapper(this, {{object.id}});'
```

JS

```
    var callback_status;
    function dajaxice_check_time_budget(data) {
        var msg = "Your program estimated duration does not match the time allocated.\n\nIs this OK?\n";        
        if (data.result == true) {
            callback_status = true;
        }
        else {
            callback_status = confirm(msg); 
        }         
    }

    function dajaxice_wrapper(obj, program_id) {
        callback_status = false;        
        Dajaxice.programcreator.check_time_budget(dajaxice_check_time_budget, { 'id': program_id });
        // Required to get callback_status set from dajaxice callback (asynchronous call via ajax)
        setTimeout(function() {
                              if ( callback_status != undefined ) {
                                  if ( callback_status == true ) {
                                      window.location = obj.href;                                 
                                  }                                      
                              };
                    }, 500);
        return callback_status;                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is:

```
<a id="download-trigger" href='{% url program_pdf object.id %}' onClick='return check_time_budget();'>Download PDF</a>

function check_time_budget() {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/program/check_duration/',
        data: { 'program_id': {{ instance.id }} },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.result != true){
                return confirm("Your program estimated duration does not match the time allocated. Is this OK?");
            }
            else {
                // This will start to load the pdf.
                window.location = jQuery('#download-trigger').attr('href');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            return false;
        }
    });            
}
```